# Prism 6 ContainsRegionWithName activate view

Tags: prism

I have converted my project from prism 4 to prism 6.3.0 and i am facing issue when i call ContainsRegionWithName.

ContainsRegionWithName is activating one of the view( which was not happening in prism 4).
This function is internally calling UpdateRegion and it calls TryRegisterRegion. But not sure why this is registering region.

Also, found that AutoPopulate behavior is activating that module.

Then i took some time to understand the existing code base.

My project does not have Imodule and it has only View and ViewModel.
My project contains 2 main ContentControl. One of them is loading menu item and another loads the respective main page based on the menu selection.

All the menu items tagged with attribute class.

```
public interface IMenuModule
    {
        Uri MainViewUri { get; }
        object MainView { get; }
    }
```

Example menu class

```
[Export(typeof(IMenuModule))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public partial class FirstMenuView
{
    public FirstMenuView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new FirstMenuViewViewModel();
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => MainView= new FirstMenuMainPageView()), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }

    public override Uri MainViewUri
    {
        get
        {
            return new Uri("FirstMenuMainPageView", UriKind.Relative);
        }
    }
```

when the user selected FirstMenu then main content control load the FirstMenuMainPageView.

This FirstMenuMainPageView has view and viewmodel as listed below.

FirstMenuMainPageView.xaml

```
<ContentControl Name="FirstMenuMainPageShellControl"
                cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static local:Regions.ShellRegion}"
                cal:RegionManager.RegionManager="{Binding Scoped}" />
```

FirstMenuMainPageView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class FirstMenuMainPageView
{
    public FirstMenuMainPageView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var model = new FirstMenuMainPageViewModel();
        DataContext = model;
        RegionManager.SetRegionManager(FirstMenuMainPageShellControl, model.Scoped);
    }
}
```

FirstMenuMainPageViewModel.cs

```
public class FirstMenuMainPageViewModel: BindableBase, IActiveAware
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>().CreateRegionManager();

    public IRegionManager Scoped
    {
        get
        {
            return _regionManager;
        }
    }

    public FirstMenuMainPageViewModel()
    {
        Scoped.RegisterViewWithRegion(Regions.ShellRegion, typeof(InternalView));
    }

    protected override void OnActivated()
    {
        base.OnActivated();
    }
}
```

and in shell.xaml file, when the menu item selected by user then either to navigate or contain that view ( did not understand this code completely )

```
_selectedModule = _selectedItem as INavigationModule;
        var shellView = OwnerWindow as IShellView;
        if (shellView != null && null != _selectedItem) shellView.ShowWaitWindow();

        //GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced);

        if (null != _selectedModule)
        {
            if (null != _selectedModule.MainView)
            {
                if (!MainRegion.Views.Contains(_selectedModule.MainView))
                {
                    // DS: never change the running system
                    var dependencyObject = _selectedModule.MainView as DependencyObject;
                    IRegionManager manager = null;
                    if (null != dependencyObject)
                        manager = RegionManager.GetRegionManager(dependencyObject);

                    MainRegion.Add(_selectedModule.MainView);

                    if (null != dependencyObject)
                        RegionManager.SetRegionManager(dependencyObject, manager ?? _regionManager);
                }
                MainRegion.Activate(_selectedModule.MainView);
            }
            else
                MainRegion.NavigationService.RequestNavigate(_selectedModule.MainViewUri);
        }
        else
            MainRegion.NavigationService.RequestNavigate(_emptyViewUri);

        var view = MainRegion.ActiveViews.FirstOrDefault();
```

from the code what i understood is View (FirstMenuMainPageView) class instance is created by MenuModule hence I have commented this line

```
//Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => MainView= new FirstMenuMainPageView()), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

and put [Export] attribute decoration to viewclass ( MEFServicelocater find this class to create the instance )

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
[RegionMemberLifetime(KeepAlive = true)]
public partial class FirstMenuMainPageView
```

Then i did not get that exception, also i feel I have to decorate this attribute to FirstMenuMainPageViewModel class as well.

Please correct me if I am doing wrong.

Regards,
Ram

Comment: There is no Prism 6.1.3.

Comment: sorry it is 6.3.0

Comment: The project moved to GitHub for v6.0 when Microsoft gave the Prism to the community.  To my knowledge this portion of the code has not changed at all. Did anything else in your code base change?

Comment: I took a look at the source on GitHub. Nothing jumped out that made me think Prism is causing this behavior.

Comment: I am a beginner of prism, so I am not sure what really wrong in the code. Hence call stack given here.

Comment: The call stack does not help.  You have provided no context of the issue.  There is no telling where the problem is and this is really a wild goose chase.  You must provide more specific information in order to help narrow down the offending code.